# Return "The resource cannot be found" into a string

Tags: c#, http

```
try
{
    context.Response.Redirect("LoginProcessss.aspx");
    return "Found";
}

catch (ThreadAbortException)
{
    throw;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    return "Page Not Found ...";
}
```

Hi, I have a page which is called LoginProcess.aspx, based on above, I change the name into LoginProcesss.aspx and it return Server Error in '/' Application. The resource cannot be found. Can I get this error message and display in the page that I do this function ?

What I need is I want display something like "Error : Page not Found ..."

Comment: Check the path of LoginProcess.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `Redirect` is actually trying to go to that page.  So if the redirect was successful (and also if it's not), it won't ever get back to that try block.

Try something like this:

```
    HttpWebResponse objResponse = null;
    var objRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create("LoginProcessss.aspx"); 
    objResponse = (HttpWebResponse) objRequest.GetResponse();
    if(objResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        return "Found";
    }else{
        return "Page Not Found ...";
    }
```